# Excel a Xml en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, xml

Tengo un desarrollo en c# que agarra un excel con unos datos en formato XML, hasta el momento agarra el archivo excel desde el programa pero al momento de guardarlo con formato XML, el archivo se guarda vacio, como puedo hacer para que guarde los datos que estan en el excel como formato xml, el siguiente codigo es donde hace la conexion al archivo excel y se supone que pasa los datos que tengo a la tabla que se convertira en xml

```
private DataTable GetTableDataXl(string XlFile)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            string Ext = Path.GetExtension(XlFile);
            string connectionString = "";
            if (Ext == ".xlsx")
            {    //para Excel 07 y superior
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =" + XlFile + "; Extended Properties = 'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
            }
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();  

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            //Obtener el nombre de la primer hoja
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dtSchema;
            dtSchema = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string[] ExcelSheetName = new string[dtSchema.Rows.Count];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                ExcelSheetName[i] = dr["cabecera"].ToString();
                i++;
            }
            conn.Close();
            //Leer todos los datos de la hoja a una tabla
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + ExcelSheetName + "]";
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt); // Llene los datos de la hoja a la tabla de datos
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Donde se supone que estas guardando?